# How do I redirect a URL with a question mark?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

The `?` is not part of a query but used as if it were an actual question. Here's an example:

```
/how-did-penicillin-change-the-world?.html
```

What's the best way to redirect that URL to something like `/news.html`?

Comment: Does it work with the ? within the URL?

Comment: No, but I want to redirect to the URL that doesn't have the ? in it.

Comment: @ScottS. Question marks are [reserved characters](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/) in URLs and therefore are required to be encoded. Your comment above is also very unclear, and your question doesn't state _where_ to redirect to...

Comment: @Dan I want to redirect it to /news.html as a catch all.

Comment: "The `?` is not part of a query" - Well, actually it is. An unencoded `?` in the URL delimits the start of the query string (whether that is the intention or not). Once you realise that then the method you use is the same for matching any other URL with a query string.

Comment: @MrWhite right, but you understand my point that this wasn't the intentional purpose.